# Removing the return spring of a rear derailleur

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear, tension

I am trying to turn my standard shifting bicycle into an automatic shifter using a motor to increase and decrease the tension in the shifter cable. The problem is that a lot of torque is required to do this, so I was considering cutting the return spring off.

I know this is permanent, so I want to make sure that I am doing the right thing before making the cut. I am planning on installing a spring with a much lower spring constant on the cable itself (see image).

[image]

This is another thread with a similar topic. Móż suggested cutting this spring.

[(Automatic Bike Project) amount of torque required to change gears?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17912/automatic-bike-project-amount-of-torque-required-to-change-gears)

I am really new to bicycle engineering, so please excuse my lack of knowledge on the topic.

Comment: How is this not just a duplicate of the linked question? Can you clarify?

Comment: @RoboKaren Sure! I want to confirm that the return spring does what I think it does and that putting a spring on the cable (as shown in the image) will have a similar effect. I essentially want to reduce the force required by putting a lighter spring in the mechanism.

Comment: You could go without a spring completely, and use a push/pull arrangement like a lawnmower throttle cable

Comment: Moz did not suggest cutting the spring as I read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called the *return* spring.  Without that spring you don't have *return*.

Without a return you would need a push / pull (stiff) activator.

Looks like commercial electronic use a cable (pull) activator.