# which motor is used to change gears in automatic gear shifting cycle now-a-days?

Tags: gears, internally-geared-hub

I am doing a project on automatic gear shifting. I need to choose which motor will be used to change the gear.
I have found a [previous question on this topic](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/17912/6852). An [answer mentioned](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/17913/6852):

> If you used a fairly hefty RC servo motor I think it could work

Which motor is used nowadays for automatic gear shifting? Which motor will be perfectly suitable for my application? How much power will be required for a gear shift and to hold the wire in a particular position?

I am interested in the exact value of torque/power required for a single gear shift in 7 geared cycle.

Comment: I assume you plan to simply pull the shift cable with a servo motor? I think the easiest way you’ll get a good answer is by pulling the shift cable on your bike with a luggage scale and convert that to pulling force (or measure the force in any other way).

Comment: If you expect the motor to hold the cable against the springs in the derailleur on its own you need a stepper motor

Comment: A stepper motor will consume far too much power. For this application (pulling and holding a cable), we should use a worm and worm-gear arrangement. This will hold the cable in position with the motor turned off, and it also offers a high ratio of often 20:1 or 50:1, which will enable use of a smaller and higher-RPM motor.

Comment: TRy to read how electronic shifting is implemented, you can learn a lot from that. I am sure that patent applications for Shimano Di2 or SRAM eTap will have a lot of information and some of it may be relevant. (they use stepper motors)

Comment: I've always assumed that stepper motors are used.

Comment: Commercial electronic shifters use a motor to move the derailleur directly, not pull/release a conventional cable, so there isn't really a direct comparison.  I am too many decades removed from working with servos to know offhand for modern parts how a stepper with enough detent torque to hold position unpowered vs a worm gear setup would compare in weight and size etc :)  (Shimano at least uses a worm gear according to wikipedia.)

Comment: Rather than build an electric derailleur use one that already exists and focus on programmatically controlling the auto shift?

Comment: The Trek Lime 3speed had  an automatic shifting system. The way I understand it worked was a front dynamo varied the voltage to a controller that pulled the cable and shifted the three speed rear hub.

Comment: I would think that electronic shifting is accomplished with brushless DC motors with position sensors.  Brushless DC motors are smaller and more efficient, and have more torque than stepper motors.

Comment: On a side, I am not sure electrically driven shifters need spring at all if you let the servo motor control the position directly all the time. In such case consumption would be much lower for shifting, and approaching zero for maintaining position. Bit position holding would have to be quite precise, and probably you would rig your own servo to do that.

Comment: @Affe there is at least one "converter" that allow turning a conventional mechanical derailleur into a wireless one, e.g. Archer D1x. It is mounted on the chainstay and does pull a short run of the cable from the derailleur.